# AttributeError: module 'ipywidgets' has no attribute 'TagsInput'

Tags: jupyter, google-colaboratory, ipywidgets

I'm trying to use `TagsInput` from `ipywidgets` in Google Colab, but I get error `AttributeError: module 'ipywidgets' has no attribute 'TagsInput'`.

I tried adding `%pip install -q ipywidgets==8.0.4` doesn't help, the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You might needed to restart Python. In databricks with dbutils, it's
`dbutils.library.restartPython()`.

You can test your version with `ipywidgets.__version__`